# Poisson process at a random time

Tags: probability, poisson-process

Given a unit rate Poisson process $\{N(t):t\ge 0\}$, we generate a process
$$A(t) = N(\int_0^t \Lambda(\tau)d\tau)$$
associated with a filtration $\mathcal{F}_t$ such that $A(t)$ is adapted and $\Lambda(t)\ge 0$ is predicatable. (we may also assume that $\Lambda(\cdot)\le c<\infty$ a.s.)

I am working on a problem that needs to determine if
$$\mathbb{E}[A(t)]  = \mathbb{E}[\int_0^t \Lambda(\tau)d\tau] $$

Intuitively this should be true because the rate function $\Lambda(\cdot)$ is predictable.

Without the predictability assumption, this cannot be true, say one can define a random time $\xi$ that $N(\xi)- \xi>1$.

Some motivations for the problem: consider a manager adjusting the future arrival rate $\Lambda(\cdot)$ based on the history information (including history arrivals). In this case, the arrival process is $A(t)$ and we expect the expected future arrivals to be the mean of the rate.

Additional assumption: as suggested by Kurt, this claim may not be true. To make the motivation work, we may add an assumption that $N(t+\int_0^s\Lambda(\tau)d\tau)-N(\int_0^s\Lambda(\tau)d\tau)\perp \mathcal{F}_s $ for all $t>0$.

Comment: Cannot be true. When $\Lambda\equiv 1$ then that integral equals $t$ and we should have $\mathbb E[A(t)]=\color{red}{\lambda}\,t$ where $\lambda$ is the intensity of the PP. Also: I would think that for general $\Lambda$ it matters if it is independent of $N$ or not.

Comment: @KurtG. Thanks for pointing out the typo, I should say that it's a unit rate Poisson process. $\Lambda$ indeed depends on the history of $A(t)$ and this is the point that confused me.

Comment: I see.  The bar in the arena is adjusted and the circus horses are supposed to jump. Jokes aside: The prime candidate I would test now is  $\Lambda(t)=N_{t-}\,.$ Its integral should have something to do with the inter arrival times of the PP who are independent and exponentially distributed.

Comment: @KurtG. Thank you again for the suggestions. However, $N(t-)$ is not necessarily predictable (but $A(t-)$ is). But if we consider $$A(t) = N(\int_0^tA(s-)ds)$$, one (possibly unique) solution is $A(t)=0$ for all $t$, which is not a contradiction to the claim.

Comment: $N_{t-}$ is predictable because it is left continuous and has  limits from the right. That equation for $A$ does indeed have the solution $A\equiv 0\,.$ Is your claim not $\mathbb E[A(t)]=\mathbb E[\int_0^tA(s-)\,ds]\,?$ In this case I see it satisfied trivially.

Comment: @KurtG. $N(t)$ need not be adapted to the filtration and $N(t-)\not\in\mathcal{F}_{t-}$.  Yes, my example is $\textbf{not}$ a contradiction.

Comment: From the wording of your post above I do not see that $N$ is not permitted (or not assumed) to be adapted to the same filtration ${\cal F}_t$ as $\Lambda\,.$ Which case is it? Not permitted, or not assumed? If the latter: I still claim that $N_{t-}$ will be the most promising path to a counter example.

Comment: @KurtG. I would say it is not permitted--- as the motivation given in the post, assuming the adaptiveness of the process $N(t)$ will give the manager future information.  At time $t$ (where $t>\int_0^tN(s-)ds$ is possible), he may know exactly the arrivals in the future as long as the rate is determined.

Answer (score 1):

After some time, here's my idea of proving the result:

consider the piecewise simple predictable functions that approximates $\Theta(t)=\int_0^t\Lambda(s)ds$ by simply partitioning the time:

with
$\Theta^n(t) = \sum_{k=0}^n\Theta(t_k)\mathbf{1}_{\{t_k\le t<t_{k+1}\}}$, where $0=t_0\le t_1 \le\cdots\le t_n = T$.

Let $\ell = \max\{k\le n: t_k\le t\}$, then for arbitrary $\epsilon\ge0$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[N(\Theta^n(t)+\epsilon)]  &= \mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbb{E}[N(\Theta^n(t)+\epsilon)-N(\Theta^n(t_\ell))\vert\mathcal{F}(t_\ell)]+N(\Theta^n(t_\ell))\right]\\
& = \mathbb{E}\left[ \left(\Theta^n(t)-\Theta^n(t_\ell)+\epsilon\right)\right]+\mathbb{E}\left[N(\Theta^n(t_\ell))\right]\\
&=\cdots\\
& = \mathbb{E}[\Theta^n(t)]+\epsilon.
\end{align}
What remains to be checked is
$$\mathbb{E}[N(\Theta(t))] = \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[N(\Theta^n(t))].$$
Because $\Theta^n(t)\nearrow \Theta(t)$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}N(\Theta^n(t)) = N(\Theta(t)-)$ for each sample path. Hence

$$\mathbb{E}[N(\Theta(t))]\ge\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[N(\Theta^n(t))] = \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[\Theta^n(t)] = \mathbb{E}[\Theta(t)].$$

But $N$ is non-decreasing, for all $\epsilon>0$
$$N(\Theta(t))\le \lim_{n\to\infty}N(\Theta^n(t)+\epsilon).$$

Hence
$$\mathbb{E}[N(\Theta(t))]\le \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[N(\Theta^n(t)+\epsilon)] = \mathbb{E}[\Theta(t)]+\epsilon.$$

Thus the claim follows from a sandwich argument.